# react-native style autocomplete in custom component

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

How do I get styles auto-complete in a custom component in react-native?

```
<MyCustomComponent style={{AlignItems: 'center'}}>
```

For example `AlignItems` and `'center'` don't autocomplete.

But if I write the styles in a `View` it will autocomplete.

```
<View style={{AlignItems: 'center'}}>
```

And no, I don't want to use Stylesheet.create().

Answer (score 1):

If you are using typescript or Flow you could type your component props and get the autocomplete as you want

```
interface IMyCustomComponentProps {
  style?: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ...
}

export class MyCustomComponent extends PureComponent<IMyCustomComponentProps> {
...
}
```

This would provide you with the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is  `style` does autosuggest only in pure react native components like `View` ,`Text` etc . But when it comes to CustomComponent React native doesnt handle like that cause you can pass any props to it with any name since you have the liberty of it.
For eg. you can pass style as a `styleObject` or simply a string, since its your own component, hence autosuggestions dont work here in custom component

```
<CustomComp style={{flex:1}}  />
```

or

```
<CustomComp style="Bring me a pizza"  />
```

Hope you get the gist. Feel free for doubts

Comment: Well it sucks. Style as a convention in react-native is for style. It should autocomplete.

Comment: yeah, i guess , it should have been handled, atleast they could have made it reserved or something.